# SettingWithCopyWarning Pandas setting value in column based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My current bit of code is a as follows:

```
            conditions = [
                (df1['item-condition'] == '1'),
                (df1['item-condition'] == '2'),
                (df1['item-condition'] == '3'),
                (df1['item-condition'] == '4')
            ]
            choices = ['Used - Like New', 'Used - Very Good', 'Used - Good', 'Used - Acceptable']
            df1['item-condition'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

I am trying to set the values in column 'item-condition' from 1 to Like New, 2 to Very Good etc etc
But with this code I get the error: `SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`
How exactly is my code wrong and is it possible to re-write it to not raise this warning?

Edit to show sample data:

```
    item-condition
0   2
1   2
2   3
3   1
```

Should be changed to:

```
    item-condition
0   Used - Very Good
1   Used - Very Good
2   Used - Good
3   Used - Like New
```

Comment: do what its saying `use .loc[` if you need help please post data as well

Comment: Try df1.loc['item-condition']

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 Changing it to `df1.loc['item-condition'] = np.select(conditions, choices)` gives the error `ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns`

Answer (score 0):

Conver it into numpy and reappend it

```
a = df1['item-condition'].to_numpy()
cond_list = [a=1,a=2,a=3,a=4]
df1['item-condition'] = np.select(cond_list,choices,'potato')
```